# continuity of function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, uniform-convergence

So here it is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{nx^2})}{1+(x-1)\ln^4(xn)}$$

$$x \in (1,\infty)$$

My task is to prove its continuity if possible.
My lead was to try proving it through uniform convergence, what do you think, is it possible?

Comment: It is possible. Use monotonicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: It's enough to show the series converges uniformly on any $[a,\infty),$ where $a>1.$ To do this, try the Weierstrass M test. I'm seeing the $n$th term as $\le \sin(1/n)/[(a-1)(\ln n)^4]$ for $n>1$ on $[a,\infty).$

Comment: Yeah, I get what you say, tried it but having a hard time to understand why is it enough to say that to prove its continuity even in (1,infinity)

Comment: Suppose you have a function on $(1,\infty)$ that is continuous on $[a,\infty)$ for each $a> 1.$ Isn't that function continuous on $(1,\infty)$?

Comment: Ohh, now I get it, that 'for each' was what I've missed, thank you